# Bread machines and low altitude my bread won't rise!

Tags: baking

I am experienced in baking; I am 65 years old and been baking and cooking for a while, but this problem has got me going crazy.

I have recently purchased two new bread machines; one is a Sanyo brand and the other one is an Oster brand. I live below sea level, and the bread I have made in them won't bake light and airy--it bakes very dense and won't rise completely. I previously had an older bread machine and it baked perfect bread every time, but I also lived in a higher altitude when I had it.

All my ingredients are fresh and I have followed the recipes to a T. What am I doing wrong? I never had this problem before until I got these new bread machines and got rid of the old one. I am so frustrated. I'm ready to just give up and throw my bread machines away.

Comment: suggested edits: remove the request for a recipe and instead ask for a method (so your post doesn't get flagged), and (please) let us know which bread machine(s) you are working with. It might make a difference. Thanks

Comment: How far below seal level do you live?

Comment: have you tried proofing your yeast, just to make sure that's not an issue?  And if you want to include your picture, it probably makes more sense to go into your profile and add it there. (click somewhere with your name or the little funny square on the top right of the page, then 'edit profile')

Comment: Can you add a description of the exact failure - does it collapse, just not rise etc. Also have you changed supplier for any ingredients?